# AngularJS filter by date

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
    <div class="well calendar" ng-model="dt">
         <datepicker min="minDate" show-weeks="showWeeks"></datepicker>
    </div>
    <div class="well">
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter: dt">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
                <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.date | date:'fullDate'}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I have an angular-ui datepicker, and I want to filter my todos list by date. But filter doesn't work.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Also, exactly how does filter not work?

Comment: Sorry, I choose date in datepicker, but my todos list is not filtered. It remains the same

Comment: Can you put a plunker/fiddle together to demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake, you need to move `ng-model` from div to `datepicker` to ensure the model is updated.

In your case, you could do the filtering inside controller using $watch. Like this:

```
function testController($scope,$filter){
    $scope.todos = [
        {done:true,text:"test 1",date:new Date(2013,11,24)},
        {done:false,text:"todo 2",date:new Date(2013,11,25)},
        {done:false,text:"todo 3",date:new Date(2013,11,26)}
   ];

   $scope.filterTodos = [];

    $scope.$watch("dt",function(newValue,oldValue,scope){
        if (newValue){
            scope.filterTodos = $filter('filter')(scope.todos, function(todo){
                console.log(todo.date.getDate());
                console.log(newValue);
                return todo.date.getDate() == newValue;
            });
        }
        else{
           scope.filterTodos = scope.todos; //no filter
        }
    });
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v3TFE/1/)

In this demo, I allow users to enter free text and filter by `date.getDate()`, you could modify the logic to filter in any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the watch as since the view is re-painted every-time the filter changes. 
So just adding the appropriate filter should work.

And yes you should move ng-model="dt" to the input element, datepicker in your case so that every time you enter any date or modify it, it update the model. And you are using the model as filter so when model changes resulting to change in filter, the view is repainted filtering the results.

Comment: it works with text, I'm not sure if it works with date. Date is a bit special, how you define `equal` is **specific to your app** (equal year,month,date or equal to minute,second,...)

Comment: You can write your own filter function, that will return true/false depending upon your condition.

Comment: See in your custom filter is iterated for the complete items present in your hg-repeat.
And for every iteration the function is passed the object. So you just have to check the object, weather it should be filtered out or not.

So for those you want to filter out just return false else return true.

Check this fiddle I am filtering Adam, likewise you can compare anything and make it work. 


Simple Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CBgcP/358/

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this most times; read a lot about creating custom app filter. But I think the quickest way, especially if you have access to the date source, and if it is coming from MySQL, just return the date from the database as an ISO Date and angularjs can then filter the date correctly.

```
date("c", strtotime($mysqlDateValueFromDb))
```